# Excel VBA function take 2 different data type and loop through collection of class module

Tags: excel, vba

I have following sub working but get #VALUE! error after change sub into function.

Working sub as follow

```
Sub Get_Tier2(ByVal myCategory As String, ByVal myMSRP As Double)

Dim ProductTiers As Collection
Dim pt As ProductTier
Dim result As String
Dim CIDTierCount As Integer
CIDTierCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set ProductTiers = New Collection

For i = 2 To CIDTierCount
    Set pt = New ProductTier
    pt.Category = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("B")
    pt.Tier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("C")
    pt.MSRP_Low = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("D")
    pt.MSRP_High = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("E")
    ProductTiers.Add pt
Next


For Each pt In ProductTiers

    If StrComp(pt.Category, myCategory) = 0 And pt.MSRP_Low < myMSRP And myMSRP < pt.MSRP_High Then
        result = pt.Tier()
        MsgBox result
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

When I change the sub to function and try to use in excel, it will return me #VALUE! in excel

```
Function Get_Tier(ByVal myCategory As String, ByVal myMSRP As Double) As String

Dim ProductTiers As Collection
Dim pt As ProductTier
Dim result As String

Dim CIDTierCount As Integer
CIDTierCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set ProductTiers = New Collection

For i = 2 To CIDTierCount
    Set pt = New ProductTier

    pt.Category = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("B")
    pt.Tier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("C")
    pt.MSRP_Low = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("D")
    pt.MSRP_High = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Rows(i).Columns("E")
    ProductTiers.Add pt
Next

For Each pt In ProductTiers
    If StrComp(pt.Category, myCategory) = 0 And pt.MSRP_Low < myMSRP And myMSRP < pt.MSRP_High Then
        Get_Tier = pt.Tier()
        Exit Function
    Else
        Get_Tier = "no match"
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Class Module ProductTier are as follow

```
Private pCategory As String
Private pTier As String
Private pMSRP_Low As Double
Private pMSRP_High As Double

Public Property Get Category() As String
    Category = pCategory
End Property

Public Property Let Category(Value As String)
    pCategory = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Tier() As String
    Tier = pTier
End Property

Public Property Let Tier(Value As String)
    pTier = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MSRP_Low() As String
    MSRP_Low = pMSRP_Low
End Property

Public Property Let MSRP_Low(Value As String)
    pMSRP_Low = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MSRP_High() As String
    MSRP_High = pMSRP_High
End Property

Public Property Let MSRP_High(Value As String)
    pMSRP_High = Value
End Property
```

And the data on CIDTier tab

Column B: ProductA

Column C: Tier 1

Column D: 0

Column E: 300

Comment: What data are you providing as parameters to the function?

Comment: The data are from excel cell. for example = Get_Tier(ProductA, 150), It works when call by sub - Call Get_Tier2(ProductA, 150), I will get the popup message box return correct Tier.

Comment: Is that exactly how it's typed in your formula?  "= Get_Tier(ProductA, 150)" if so then it's looking for a named range.  You'd need "=Get_Tier("ProjectA", 150)" in order to pass a string

Comment: @Sobigen:T he function is referring other cell, so it would be like "=Get_Tier(BB219,M219)", Cell BB219 Has Value ProductA, Cell M219 has Value 150, I do tried "=Get_Tier(""""&BB219&"""",M219)" and not work as well

Comment: Very strange, try setting a breakpoint on the top line (Function Get_Tier...) and see where the error occurs. The function should run when the sheet is re-calculated.  Double check what the inputs are coming in as, it seems like it has to be something with the inputs if the sub works.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Culprit

```
CIDTierCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

If you throw a debug marker on that line and print what

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

returns, you get `1048576`. This will overflow the Integer you are trying to place it in.

#### Possible Solution

From what you are doing, it looks like you want a count of rows, you can try changing the code to the following:

```
CIDTierCount = Worksheets("CIDTier").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

#### Why this works

In Excel, each worksheet has a range that is defined as the UsedRange. This range goes from A1 to the farthest right column that is formatted or contains data and the lowest row that is formatted or contains data.

Comment: :thank you for your input, I do change the code to -ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CIDTier").Range("A:A").UsedRange.Rows.Count but still getting the #Value! Error

Comment: How many rows are you working with?  The integer will still overflow if it's more than 32768 but if it's working as a sub that's probably not the case.

Comment: @Sobigen: The rows at CIDTier tab is 5 rows and expected around 100 rows in the future.